# Как получить доступ к подэлементам в ListView

Tags: c#, dll

У меня есть несколько столбцов в ListView. Тут заполняется первый. Как заполнить подэлементы в ListView ? 
Хочется попробовать сделать свое приложение (подобие диспетчера задач, чисто для практики) модульным. 
Какие функции можно вынести в библиотеку и как примерно их описать ?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KillAppProc
{
    public partial class KillProcess : Form
    {
        Process[] procesess;
        public KillProcess()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            procesess = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in procesess)
            {
                ProcesessInfo.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчёт ListView делайте так:

```
ProcesessInfo.Columns.Add("Process Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
ProcesessInfo.Columns.Add("Process ID", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

ProcessInfo.Items.AddRange(processes.Select(CreateLVItem));

// ...
ListViewItem CreateLVItem(Process p)
{
    var name = p.ProcessName;
    var pid = p.Id;
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(name);
    item.SubItems.Add(name);
    item.SubItems.Add(pid.ToString());
    return item;
}
```

Насчёт разноса функций по библиотекам -- вы архитектор, вам и решать. Если нет идей, пишите всё в одну кучу сначала, когда увидите логические объединяемые куски, отделите их. Рефакторинг рулез форэва!

Comment: ругается на эту строчку:
ProcesessInfo.Items.AddRange(procesess.Select(CreateLVItem)); 
//имеет несколько недопустимых параметров.
//не совсем понял суть: processes.Select(CreateLVItem)

Comment: Нет, не забыл.

Comment: Хм. А какую ошибку выдаёт? Попробуйте разбить на куски:

    var items = processes.Select(CreateLVItem);
    ProcessInfo.Items.AddRange(items);

Какую строку компилятор не переварил?

Comment: ProcessInfo.Items.AddRange(items);
как я понял не может преобразовать IEnumerable в массив. ведь (processes является массивом ?)

Comment: а, понятно. попробуйте тогда ProcessInfo.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо. Заработало.